# gnome3 - cannot replace window manager to metacity

Tags: gnome, window-manager

When I installed gnome3 for the first time my window manager was `metacity`.
I have to reinstall gnome3, and after that my window manager is now `gnome-shell`.
If I try `metacity --replace &` I lose the gnome dock, top bar...

All questions I read about how to change a window manager concluded to `[window-manager] --replace`, and it's not working for me.

So how can I change a window manager?
Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to get Metacity running is to install
*GNOME FlashBack (Metacity)* session with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

After installation select *GNOME FlashBack (Metacity)* on login screen.